# Is it possible to keep the GUI (pyQT5) responsive while running a long lasting function from the main thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, pyqt5

i have the following problem: My program imports a function that plots and saves a large amount of data with matplotlib, and therefore it takes 1-2 minutes to finish. As matplotlib is not thread-safe, I have to run it from the main GUI-thread. But this freezes the GUI for the amount of time the function needs to finish.

Is there a way to run this function in a thread-safe way without freezing the GUI?

Comment: Maybe use `multiprocessing` instead? Run the task on a different process. ;-) If you need to pass complex data structures or have bidirectional communication, maybe use a higher abstraction layer like [osBrain](https://github.com/opensistemas-hub/osbrain).

Comment: You can use `QApplication.processEvents()` periodically to run the events in the event queue.